# is not assignable to type Knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, webstorm, knex.js

I'm a newbie who doesn't know how to do it, Knex has two variable names, how should I get the method to return the variable I want。

```
import {knex, Knex} from 'knex';

public async createConnection(): Promise<Knex> {
  const config: Knex.Config = {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: this.config.host,
      port: this.config.port,
      user: this.config.user,
      password: this.config.password,
      database: this.config.database
    },
    debug: this.config.debug,
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'migrations'
    }
  };

  const db = knex(config);
  await db.raw('select 1');

  return db;
};
```

The above code webstorm reported an error

```
TS2322: Type 'Knex<any, unknown[]>' is not assignable to type 'Knex<any, Record<string, any>[]>'.
The types returned by 'select().first().stream(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'PassThrough & AsyncIterable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'PassThrough & AsyncIterable<never>'.
Type 'PassThrough & AsyncIterable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'AsyncIterable<never>'.
The types returned by '[Symbol.asyncIterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'Promise<IteratorResult<any, any>>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<IteratorResult<never, any>>'.
Type 'IteratorResult<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<never, any>'.
Type 'IteratorYieldResult<any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<never, any>'.
Type 'IteratorYieldResult<any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<never>'.
Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public async createConnection(): Promise<Knex> {
        const config: Knex.Config = {
            client: 'mysql',
            connection: {
                host: this.config.host,
                port: this.config.port,
                user: this.config.user,
                password: this.config.password,
                database: this.config.database
            },
            debug: this.config.debug,
            migrations: {
                tableName: 'migrations'
            }
        }
        const db: Knex = knex(config)

        await db.raw('select 1');

        return db;
  
    }
```

Comment: I've solved it and just need to add Knex